# C# Npgsql connection checker Exception Throw System.NullReferenceException 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: c#, postgresql, nullreferenceexception, npgsql

My code try to check is the PostgreSQL server running and accessible by given credentials for given database. Use the Npgsql NuGet. If all the data, also IP, Port, User, Pass and Database are correct, the code returns true.
Here is a code:

```
public Boolean InsertInToPGSQL()
        {
            var pg_con_string = "Server=" + sqlinsertserver + ";" + "Port=" + sqlinsertport + ";" + "Database=" + sqlinsertdatabase + ";" + "User ID=" + sqlinsertusername + ";" + "Password=" + sqlinsertpassword + ";";
            var pg_connetion = new NpgsqlConnection(pg_con_string);
            try
            {
                if (pg_connetion != null)
                {
                    pg_connetion.Open();
                    pg_connetion.Close();
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {

                    return false;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

The problem is if i write an IP address where is no server running, or bad port, or wrong user/pass, database, i receive always on:

```
pg_connetion.Open();
```

An error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

The problem is that a catch (Exception) don't catch this error and returns simple false.
I don't need to deal with type of errors, like wrong credential or IP / port, just need to have true on successful connection to the PostgreSQL server and false for any other case.
How to deal with this error?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get exception details you need to do catch(Exception ex) and within catch block you can do ex.InnerException or ex.Message to find the exception details. In your case, the connection object is null because of incorrect parameters. I would do a null check on connection object before connection.open() which would avoid object ref not set to instance. Hope that should suffice your need. Change your code to following and send me the ex.Message and ex.InnerException values.

```
public static class Application
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        if (InsertInToPGSQL())
            Console.WriteLine("Connection successful");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Connection failed");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }       


    public static Boolean InsertInToPGSQL()
    {
        var pg_con_string = "";
        var pg_connetion = new NpgsqlConnection(pg_con_string);
        try
        {
            if (pg_connetion != null)
            {
                pg_connetion.Open();
                pg_connetion.Close();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

``

[image]

Comment: Hello! Have tested with if (pg_connetion.Equals(null)) but nothing, same error.

Comment: You need to open connection only when its not null. So, your if condition should be like this if (pg_connetion != null)

Comment: Have try but no success. `if (pg_connetion != null)
                {
                    pg_connetion.Open();
                    pg_connetion.Close();
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    return false;
                }`

Comment: OK. Use the code from my answer and put a breakpoint on catch block to watch the exception details.

Comment: Have the same error: `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
`  The catch ex give me the next content: `Exception while connecting.` I think the problem is that if a call the command to connect, i receive this error. The pg_connection is never null, maybe are the paramterest for the server connection wrong, but they are present and is not null. I have no idea how to move forward.

Comment: Looks like some parameters in the connection object is not set. Exception while connecting can be due to many reasons like Firewall issues, DNS resolution etc. Make sure you are able to ping the server. Are you able to connect to server and database using a client like pgadmin ?

Comment: This is a problem that i wish to solve with catch. In a case that is a parameter wrong, i wish that return a false, and true only if the connection is success. If the connection is success, i have true as response, but if is not connected, it don't returns me a false. I have tested with good parameter of port 5432 (receive a true) and false parameter (port is wrong, 54321) but the catch do the job, only the pg_connetion.Open(); make this trouble with NullReferenceException

Comment: Sorry I did not get your problem. Your catch block will catch any error that is caused when connection is opened which would return false. So, your code is already doing what you want to. Have I understood your problem correctly?

Comment: Excuse me for my bad English. Well, the code still works, but it break  with `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` and stop working. I need somehow to "disable" this System.NullReferenceException to interrupt the program.

Comment: I ran the code just now on visual studio as a console app and it does not interrupt the flow. It goes into the catch block and returns false. You will see "Connection failed" on the console. Try it.

Comment: I changed the code and pasted a picture of my error. This NullReferenceException happens only if the ip or port are wrong, so in a case that it try to connect to unexciting server. If the username or password are wrong, i receive the catch, but not the NullReferenceException. You can see on the picture the error that occur. This part of code have to check the connection to server, and if all the parameters are OK, to return a true, and in all other cases false.

Comment: Aah now I know. On your image just uncheck the checkbox which says "Break when this type of exception is thrown" and run the code again. It should go to the catch block. Its a setting of Visual Studio so you dont miss important exceptions and its does not mean your code will just blow up and not go to catch block. Hope it makes sense and helps,

Comment: @PeterBoldt : Could you up vote my answer if that helped? Thanks

Comment: No worries. Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late, but for those like me who felt on this thread it can be usefull.

I faced the same issue until i update the NpSql nuget package. I was on 4.0.3, and update to 4.1.10. Finaly it fixed the problem.